# Unable to launch VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am running into an issue with Visual Studio code where i could not able to launch it in Windows 8.1. It is working fine untill few days back. Even though it shows two processes named Code 32 bit are running in Task Manager, i cannot see the VSCode UI. I tried going to folder and right click and click on Open with Code, but no luck.

Even after uninstall and installing the VSCode also, i am running into same issue. Does anyone face this issue before?

Is there a way i can clean uninstall VSCode and re install?

Thanks,
Phani

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling, rebooting, then reinstalling to see if it corrects the issue? Have you installed any other software recently?

Comment: what version of code are you using? Do you have some special characters in the path where VSCode is intalled?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try AppData\Local\Code\bin\code.cmd ?

vscode is running by update.exe